# How can I choose option from a drop-down list in IE that's not entirely preloaded with VBA?

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, tags

I am trying to create a `VBA macro` that will automatically select the item from a drop-down list from a website. Even though the options in the drop-down list have id tag, but not the entire list is `preloaded`, therefore it will throw an error when I hard code to choose the option's ID.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**First pic: This is when the drop-down list when it's first clicked (not all the options are shown)**

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Second pic: Once I scroll the drop-down list to the bottom, more options and their tag IDs show up!**

Even though I know the tag ID of the last option in the drop-down menu, I couldn't hard code to choose it because it `does not exist` on the webpage until the drop-down menu is scrolled down and the options are shown.

> How can I do that via VBA to have all the options shown?

Thanks in advance! :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
(head removed)

<body class="mainframe new-component-style" id="mainBody">
  <form name="form1" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="form1" onsubmit="doSubmit();return true;" action="/pagesUTF8/auftrag_allgemeinauftrag.jsp" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="bgcContent" id="bg_site">
      <div id="bg_site_inner">
        <div class="ContentBox ContentBox2Spalten">
          <div class="ContentBoxContainer">
            <div>
              <table width="100%" id="AjaxCon35" aria-live="polite" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 0px;" colspan="4">
                      <div style="padding: 4px 0px; width: 100%; -ms-overflow-y: auto; max-height: 570px;">
                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr class="OutTabBodyBack_white" id="AjaxCon32" aria-live="polite">
                              <td class="OutTabBody_NoBorder">
                                <div class="component-group" style="width: 100%;">
                                  <div class="tagbox-wrapper ng-non-bindable">
                                    <div class="tagBox single-select" id="ATagBox10ASSPLJ" style="top: 431.69px; width: 258.02px; position: fixed; z-index: 9999;" name="ATagBox05ASSPLJ">
                                      <div class="tagBoxWrapper focus" id="ATagBox05ASSPLJ" name="ATagBox05ASSPLJ">
                                        <div class="selectWrapper" style="display: none;">
                                          <div>
                                            <select name="ASSPLJ" class="form-element ng-non-bindable" id="ASSPLJ">
                                              <option id="ATagBox07#ASSPLJ#1187" selected="selected" value="1187"></option>
                                            </select>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                          /* <![CDATA[ */
                                          addToGwtFunctionQueue('initTagBox', ['ASSPLJ', {
                                            "noEntryFoundTxt": "No entries found",
                                            "stdTxt": "Please select",
                                            "isMultiSelect": false,
                                            "autoReturn": "DoAjaxProjekt(\"AjaxCon32\", \"ASSPLJ\", \"3\", \"2001906\");",
                                            "isOpenToTop": false
                                          }]);
                                          /* ]]> */
                                        </script>
                                        <div class="outerWrapper" style="width: 100%;">
                                          <div class="dropDownButtonContainer"><button class="dropDownButton" id="TagBoxDropDownASSPLJ" type="button"><span class="icon-arrow-down"></span></button></div>
                                          <div class="fakeSelect" id="ATagBox03ATagBox08ASSPLJ" style="width: 225px;">
                                            <div class="fakeSelectInnerWrapper active">
                                              <div title="Yin" class="tag-value ellipsis" id="ATagBox06#ASSPLJ#1187"><span>Yin</span></div>
                                              <div class="textBoxSearchWrapper"><input class="textBoxSearchWrapper" id="ATagBox01ASSPLJ" type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="fakeDropDown" style="height: 400px; overflow: auto; display: block; position: absolute; -ms-overflow-y: scroll; -ms-zoom: 1;">
                                        <div style="position: relative; -ms-zoom: 1;">
                                          <div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 1</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#261">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 2</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#385">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 3</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1045">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 4</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1032">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 5</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#257">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 6a</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#708">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 7</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1123">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 8</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#4">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 9</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#6">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 10</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#10">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 11</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1034">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 12</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#269">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 13</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#9">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 14</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1049">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 15</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#454">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 16</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#706">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 17</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1175">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 18</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#1037">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 19</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tag" id="ATagBox02#ASSPLJ#709">
                                              <div class="ellipsis" style="padding-right: 2px; float: left;">John 20</div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div tabindex="0" class="dropdown">
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" onclick="SelectTabelle('OSG021187');"><span>Go to details</span></a></li>
                                      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" onclick="SelectTabelle('OSG352-1187');"><span>Send e-mail</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <div class="btn-group new-componenent-style"><a class="btn btncol-secondary dropdown-toggle" aria-label="Options" data-tooltip="Options"><span class="icon-more"></span></a></div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I try to check the code and found that it is not the actual Select..option dropdown but it is designed with DIV tags. There is no visible event in code which trigger to load the rest of the elements. I suggest you try to activate the last visible value of dropdown. It can help to scroll the dropdown and it can load new values. Then you can put some wait statements in your code. So that your code will be pause till the new elements get load and then you can try to select the last element. If possible you can try to provide the sample HTML code which can produce the issue. We can try to test it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for getting back to me! You were right, it was a 'fake drop-down menu' with _div_ tag. I thought of doing the same thing to scroll down the entire list so that all the tags are visible. But I tried several ways trying to trigger an event to scroll down the _fake drop-down menu_ but to no avail. Would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: I suggest you do not post the picture of code. Post your code using a code snippet. So that we can use that code to test the issue. If the site is publicly available then you can try to share the URL of the page. We will try to visit it to reproduce the issue with the IE browser. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT It's a private website with access only so the best I can do is to post the code snippet here! Hope that will help you to understand more about the problem and give me some pointers! Appreciate that in advance!